# Determine Google OAuth2

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-authentication

I'm a little lost, and not having much success accessing Google Picasa web albums (when authentication is required).  I'm not even able to create an authentication token.  I'm trying to do this all on the server, so need to setup this up so that I can access my personal picasa web albums without any user input.  (server-side code:  c#)

I'm following this
https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Auth

I'm stuck at item #4 since I intend to not prompt the user at all (there is no user in this case).

So if these are not the basic steps to follow, can someone please provide a link or brief understanding of how I should:

1. Authenticate server-side with Picasa Api with OAuth2 Then perform
2. simple task such as listing photos from a private Album
3. complex task such as uploading a photo

I've managed to upload photo's in the past, but not with OAuth2.  I'm really looking for a definitive guide/outline is all.  I can figure out the specifics, I'm just not certain that I'm on the right path.  My current path has lead me to:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount
but I'm wondering if this is where I should be and if this is going to work with Picasa API or not.

Thanks for any help.

Karl..

Comment: Reviewing other posts in the google-oauth category and seeing a lot of ZERO answers.  I'm about to throw in the towel on accessing the Picasa Web Album API and maybe go with AWS S3 storage instead and their API's.

Comment: This is something that I am actively trying to solve, and as I progress will be providing links to relevant topics.  For example, this G+ community I'm hoping proves useful:  https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/107137198518854169493

Comment: I'm here now:  https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#usingkeys looking at Service accounts.  This seems appropriate for what I am trying to accomplish which is what I looked at before but didn't see the clear of directions before.  Trying it out now.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth2 flows are mostly designed for a user consenting to give another app access to resources. Not all authorization servers (like Google) provide non-user OAuth flows (like resource owner). Instead, some (like Google) provide API keys that are meant for your scenario, and are in essence app specific credentials. Not all systems have API keys.

Another possibility (since you own everything here), is to obtain an `access_token` with a user flow once. Keep the `access_token` *and* the `refresh_token`. Then use `refresh_tokens` in your app to renew expiring `access_tokens`.

The cleanest solution in your case is probably to use an API key.

Comment: This is good feedback Eugenio.  I was fixed on this notion that OAuth2 was the end-all to be-all and everything else was becoming obsolete.  OK, with this I will look again for a Picasa Web Album API Key and see about connecting on the back-end with it.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, see this is where I go wrong, following this:  https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Auth
They specifically suggest " If your application already uses those options, we recommend migrating to OAuth 2.0"